# React: problem with putting object into "useState"

Tags: reactjs

could you please help me,
I add the ability to edit the date after adding.
I get obj in TraningForm from TraningApp. I want to put this object into "useState", but for some reason this moment ignored. Although this object may be in the props, and I can get it safely:

[image]

Could you please explain to me what did I do wrong?

Code: https://github.com/tati-simonenko/22

Comment: Please paste code and image here. Links might break in future, and this won't be as useful for users coming in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two issues in your code.

1. In `TraningForm` form should be updated whenever `obj` changes. Need to add a `useEffect` hook below.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setForm(obj);
  }, [obj]);
```

2. In `EditObj` method there was a mistake. It should be `...item` instead of `...prevTraining`.

```
  const EditObj = (obj) => {
    setTraining((prevTraining) =>
      prevTraining.map((item) => {
        if (item.id == obj.id)
          return { ...item, date: obj.date, passed: obj.passed };
        return item;
      })
    );
  };
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-forest-jofsl?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2):

You pass the `obj` property as the [initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate): `useState(obj)`. Thus the `form` state is only set once.

```
const [form, setForm] = useState(obj);
```

Update the `form` state whenever the `obj` property changes.

```
const [form, setForm] = useState(obj);

useEffect(() => setForm(obj), [obj]);
```